# Sending big files via http post method using StringEntity with little heap size

Tags: android, http, post, out-of-memory

Let's think over this situation. You have a small heap, about 15-16MB and you want to send a huge file, but not as big as heap size via REST post. In Android there's a whole API to do it but it requires you to enclose data in StringEntity where there are only up to two params. String which is body and Charset. Let's say you have a file which is about 10MB. Everything is going well until you are putting data into StringEntity where an Exception occurs: OutOfMemory with description about full stack.

How do I solve this problem without chunking data?

Answer (score 1):

Use a `FileEntity` instead. That will stream the data into the request instead of loading it into memory.

Comment: It's a way but sadly i have to load it into memory. Firstly i have to put there few params, not only file. Secondly i have to do some things with it. If anyone cares encoding with base64 can help a bit.

Comment: Why do you need to load the entire file into memory? Can't you do your processing while reading using a `FileInputStream` and then hand it off to the request using a `InputStreamEntity`?

Comment: If you have to load the whole file into memory *even before sending it* then your question was posed incorrectly. You can *definitely* upload big files using streaming techniques.

Comment: Ok, i need this file coz i have to put it's content into body and i need to hash it too.

Comment: All the usual hash functions can be calculated in a blockwise - read streaming - manner, there is still no need to read the whole file into memory. You can easily set up a chain like `FileInputStream -> HashCalculation (extends InputStream) -> InputStreamEntity` which is ok if you need to know the hash at the end of the transmission. If you need it before sending the request, ie. to include it in a request header, simply read the file twice.

Comment: Thx for clues. Seems good : ) I have to think about this and i'll write what i did.